# Showing $\frac14 (1 -\cos 2\theta)^2 = \frac18(3 -5\cos 2\theta)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have an example which I have:

$$D = \frac{2}{\sin^4\theta} \tag{1}$$

Which in the notes goes to

$$D = \frac{2}{\frac14 (1 -\cos 2\theta)^2} \tag{2}$$

I understand that part.. but the next part in the notes... it goes to

$$D = \frac{16}{3 -5\cos 2\theta} \tag{3}$$

I have having some serous trouble getting from $(2)$ to $(3)$, as I keep getting stuck in a loop of trig identities where $\cos 2\theta$ end up with a $\cos^2\theta$ identity, and visa versa...

> Can anyone give an idea how to get from $(2)$ to $(3)$?

Comment: $$D = \dfrac{2}{\frac14 (1 -cos2(\theta))^2]}=\dfrac{8}{1+\cos^22\theta-2\cos2\theta}=\dfrac{8}{1+\frac{1+\cos4\theta}{2}-2\cos2\theta}$$

Comment: Something is funky.  When $\theta$ is an odd number times $\pi/4$, #2 gives $8$ but #3 gives $16/3$.  Is there a term containing $\cos(4\theta)$ floating around somewhere?

Comment: Thanks guys, so I was on the right track, I had gotten what Nosrati had shown, but as you said Oscar, there isn't a cos(4θ) anywhere else.... the next part is .... D = 16 / [ 3- 5 cos(2θ)]

Comment: The notes must be wrong. It happens.

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$$ and $$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$$